# alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex never called

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uialertview, ios6.1

Please excuse me if something is not post right... first time posting.

I have seen a few questions simular to this but none with the same problem. I am running IOS 6.1 and Xcode 4.6. The problem is that didDismiss is never called, only willDismiss. My code is below along with the log output. Any ideas?

```
#import "MenkLabUIAlertTestViewController.h"

@interface MenkLabUIAlertTestViewController ()

@end

@implementation MenkLabUIAlertTestViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


}
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *av  = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Encrypting File(s)" message:@"Please wait..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    //    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [av show];
    [av dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
}

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"willDISMIS");
}

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"didDISMIS");
   }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Log output:

2013-07-08 17:27:04.055 testUIAlertView[10534:11303] willDISMIS

This is just a test app, however, it is the exact same problem that exists in my current application.

Thanks in advanced. Been racking my head on this all day!

Comment: try dismissing with 0 instead of -1

Comment: Please see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32594226/4018041

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this an artifact of the fact that you are showing, then immediately dismissing the alert view in the same method -- you would never actually do this in a real app. If you create a property for the alert view, and then do the test like below, it works fine:

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    self.av  = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Encrypting File(s)" message:@"Please wait..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [self.av show];
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlertView) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}


-(void)dismissAlertView {
    [self.av dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
}

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"willDISMIS");
}

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"didDISMIS");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue, as a workaround we added a selector Method which runs after some delay which will instead trigger the dismissal of alert view. I am not sure why it does not work if we ask the alert to to dismiss immediately after it is shown. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. For me it was related to trying to programatically dismiss it with a button index on -1. We ended up going down a different path in the end for other reasons. However, There is a cancel button index on the actionsheet that you can try calling it with.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem once. For me the problem  was caused by a collision between animations. The `didDismiss` selector is called when the animation ends. If another animation is started between `willDismiss` and `didDismiss` then in some rare circumstances the `didDismiss` doesn't have to be called.

Also note that it never works well if you try to dismiss the alert before it is fully displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I have added. That solves my problem.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
     {
     }
}
```