# The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<Appname>.app/<App name>: FailWithError: , topMostAlert

Tags: ios, objective-c

On Apple Application Uploader I got this error:

`The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<Appname>.app/<App name>: FailWithError: , topMostAlert`.

I searched my code for `FailWithError:` and `topMostAlert`.
I didnt find these in my code except for `topMostAlert` used to dismiss `UIAlertView`

```
Class UIAlertManager = NSClassFromString(@"_UIAlertManager");
UIAlertView *alertView = [UIAlertManager performSelector:@selector(topMostAlert)];
[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
```

I know this error is because of using a selector in your own code or third party code that has the same name as some selector that is marked as non-public (Apple Provided API).

I am adding a screenshot of framework used in my code.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You got rejected because you are using a private class **UIAlertManager** (via `_UIAlertManager`). Change your code so it uses only public `APIs` and it will get through the review process.

Comment: I figured out same Thanks. I actually want to dismiss previous UIAlertView before showing new one. so that previous is not there. in ios7 we can do this through UIAlertManager.

Comment: topMostAlert issue is gone but Apple still show a warning 

`The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<Appname>.app/<App name>: FailWithError:`

its warning now.

Comment: Just ignore the warning. It's nothing. It just means that one of your methods is named the same as Apple's.

Comment: what if i want to find that line ? i want to refractor it.

Comment: Make a text search in your project. Remember to switch on searching the linked frameworks.

Comment: I could not find that "failWithError:" in my code. Thats the problem. how can this happen ?